# "Больной нуждается в уходе врача, и чем дальше он уходит, тем лучше"

Tags: омонимы, однокоренные-слова

В одном из вопросов (давно) тут уже звучал этот афоризм. Но меня интересует слово "уход". Как получилось, что "уход" — это удаление человека откуда-нибудь и одновременно — опека? Или это просто омонимы?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это сейчас уход1 и уход2-омонимы, этимологически  это родственники. 
От сущ. ХОД образован глагол ходить и многие производные от него. У глагола ходить была краткая форма *хаdjati(черед. о/а), из неё развилось слово хажати, давшее хаживать(ходить-"Он не раз хаживал")и ухаживать -"ходить за кем-то", "заботиться". По сути ухаживать и есть заботливо ходить, двигаться возле больного, который сам ходить не мог,прислуживать,  угождать. Современные значения разошлись, и слова превратились в омонимы.

Answer (score 2):

Это не ответ, а просто наблюдение. Афоризм хороший и очень жизненный. Но мне не совсем нравится "нуждается в уходе врача". Врач назначает лечение, называть это "уходом" я бы не стала. Ухаживают родственники, медсестры, сестры милосердия и сиделки, но не врачи... Мне так кажется...

Comment: Это понятно. Но, я думаю, тут чуть-чуть пожертвовали смыслом ради игры слов

Answer (score 1):

Уход-опека от "ухаживать"